How can I get the balance of a solana account using c#?
Every time I try to get the balance of a solana account by using its public key, it shows me zero. Can anyone help me?
FreyaXYaCwVy86BdNECd7BXnqEvFUbt3p6d2B5eS5zDv - address of the solana account I am trying
I have tried changing Cluster.DevNet to Cluster.TestNet and I have also tried to use async but is still not working.
using Solnet.Rpc;
using Solnet.Wallet;


var main = new SolanaProg();
main.GetBal("FreyaXYaCwVy86BdNECd7BXnqEvFUbt3p6d2B5eS5zDv");

class SolanaProg
{
    public void GetBal(string pubKey)
    {
        var rpcClient = ClientFactory.GetClient(Cluster.DevNet);
        var balanceResult = rpcClient.GetBalance(new PublicKey(pubKey));
        Console.WriteLine(balanceResult.Result.Value);
        if (balanceResult.Result.Value  == 0)
        {
            balanceResult = rpcClient.GetBalance(new PublicKey(pubKey));
            Console.WriteLine(balanceResult.Result.Value);
        }   
    }
}


The public key you mentioned does not exist in the "Testnet" or "Devnet" environment, hence returns a zero balance.
For example, Testnet, does not exist:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/FreyaXYaCwVy86BdNECd7BXnqEvFUbt3p6d2B5eS5zDv?cluster=testnet
It exists on Mainnet:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/FreyaXYaCwVy86BdNECd7BXnqEvFUbt3p6d2B5eS5zDv
So you just need to change to use the correct cluster where the account exists.
